# In German, how to say: "when you just saw an awe-inspiring example to follow, which made you want to be just like that person"?

Tags: expression, french

We were having a conversation in French about a certain businessman who visited our hospital, and I said jokingly:

> Je viens de le croiser dans le couloir et il a tout du homme d’affaires. Un jour, il a... enfin, on connaît la suite. Tout le monde a son nom à la bouche, après tout. Voilà un gentleman qui n’est sûrement pas en manque de louanges. **Ça laisse rêveur**, non ? Qui sait ?! Peut-être qu’un jour, je pourrai...

I was wondering how I'd express the same idea in German. This is where I'd have said:

> Gerade eben bin ich ihm im Flur begegnet, und er ist ein Geschäftsmann durch und durch. Eines Tages hat er ... aber der Rest ist doch Geschichte. Schließlich ist er in aller Munde. Da kann man ja gar nicht genug Beifall klatschen. **Wirklich sehr inspirierend**! Wer weiß, vielleicht werde ich irgendwann ja auch mal ...

The expression "*Ça (me) laisse rêveur*", literally meaning "*It leaves (me) daydreaming*", is used ...

- *when you just saw an awe-inspiring example (of what a businessman{X} should be) that everyone could stand to follow, and it inspired you -- made you want -- to be just like him/her.*

Another instance where you use this expression might be ...

- *when you hear that one of your friends has started dating a famous actor under most unexpected circumstances.* "*Ça laisse rêveur !*"

My phrasing with "*inspirierend*" seems rather lacking in comparison, though. This expression doesn't translate easily into other languages. How is this idea commonly/idiomatically expressed in German?

Comment: I liked your "inspirierend". Why do you think it's not good enough?

Comment: Google suggests *It makes you wonder, right?* as a translation to English, which makes more sense in the context. I like the *inspirierend*, but changing a question to an exclamation may be a significant change.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow the image of a businessman making you daydream doesn’t really connect for me. Anyhow, these common phrases take up the general picture, although you would find them more in the (romantic) context of your dating-the-movie-star example:

> Da kann man ja ins Schwärmen kommen!
>
> Zum Träumen schön!
>
> Ein wahr gewordener Traum!
>
> Das ist ja wie im Traum!

Comment: Bitte nicht die Einrückungen für Codeblöcke verwenden, weil dann zum Einen eine Festbreitenschrift verwendet, zum Anderen nicht umgebrochen wird.

Comment: Hi. You can see it as "*a top-notch businessman everyone admires, the best of the best in the business*".

Answer (score 1):

Die deutsche Fassung, die du in der Frage anbietest, ist etwas zu umständlich (schriftsprachlich) formuliert. So spricht man nicht. Idiomatisches (alltagstypisches) Deutsch wäre etwa:

> Grade bin ich dem im Flur begegnet. Der ist ein Geschäftsmann durch und durch. Einmal hat er... na, egal, das wär' jetzt zu lang. Aber den kennt wirklich jeder. Der wird ja bewundert noch und noch. Der Wahnsinn! Da könnte man sich eine Scheibe abschneiden...

Statt "der Wahnsinn" kann man auch sagen:

- Echt der Hammer!
- Eieiei!
- Irre!
- Du glaubst es nicht!
- Unglaublich!

(Ich teile allerdings Florians Unverständnis, wieso man einen Geschäftsmann so fürchterlich toll finden sollte. Geschäftsmänner sind typischerweise auf eines aus: Geld verdienen, und zwar möglichst viel. Das mag zwar praktisch sein, aber Bewunderung würde ich dafür nicht unbedingt aufbringen. Vielleicht meintest du gar nicht *Geschäftsmann* sondern irgend etwas anderes? Eine im allgemeinen geschliffene Persönlichkeit?)

Comment: Mit geht's hinsichtlich des Sprachlevels beim Ausgangsbeispiel genauso. Für ein Alltagsgespräch hört sich das Ganze für mich ziemlich gekünstelt an, und diese Lobhudeleien, mein lieber Mann... Wär nicht mein Fall und daher fällt mir dazu auch nichts Vernünftiges ein. Schön, hier eine aufs Alltägliche heruntergebrochene Version von @Christian Geiselmann spendiert bekommen zu haben, da kann ich mir dann eher etwas darunter vorstellen.

Answer (score 1):

This is my way of understanding the French text:

> Ich bin ihm gerade im Flur über den Weg gelaufen. Einmal hat er ja ...
>   naja, du weißt schon. Er tritt auf wie ein Geschäftsmann. Und alle
>   reden nur noch von ihm. Dem / Diesem Herrn braucht sicher niemand mehr zu sagen, wie
>   toll er ist. Da könnte man fast neidisch werden, nicht wahr? Aber wer weiß, vielleicht kann ich auch mal irgendwann ...

Comment: Klingt auch sehr glaubwürdig. Wobei ich mich immer noch frage, was an Leuten, die nur Geschäftemachen im Kopf haben, eigentlich so hinreißend sein soll. Man denke auch an die despektierliche Bezeichnung "Koofmich" für einen Geschäftsmann. Nun weiß ich aber nicht, ob vielleicht *homme d'affaires* anders konnotiert ist bei unseren westlichen Nachbarn und Freunden.

Comment: @Christian: Ich hatte mich gewundert über das "il a tout **du** homme d'affaires" und nicht "d'un homme d'affaires" ("de l'homme d'affaires" ginge wohl gar nicht). Mir erschien das mit dem "du" idiomatisch, aber ich kenn's halt nicht. Für mich ist das ganze Gespräch angestrengt auf 'angeberisch' und 'schaumschlägerisch' gebürstet, da hab ich mir gedacht: Manche haben es anscheinend nötig. Andererseits: Einen cleveren Geschäftsmann kann man vielleicht schon bewundern, aber doch nicht dafür, dass er gerade warum auch immer der angesagteste Typ auf der Station ist...